# WebSocketStompClient won't connect to SockJS endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

I'm playing around with the new (as of version 4.2) java STOMP client support.  My starting point is the getting started guide ([Using WebSocket to build an interactive web application](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)).

The following endpoint is provided in the example:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
}
```

I can successfully connect using the browser client.  When attempting to connect to this endpoint using the java stomp client using the following:

```
WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient();
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
String url = "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/hello";       
ListenableFuture<StompSession> future = stompClient.connect(url,myHandler);
```

I encounter the following exception:

```
08:56:30.629 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.m.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession - Failed to connect session id=4e6737da-8f68-691d-375f-9e46f48bc149
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [HTTP/1.1 200 OK
] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.parseStatus(WsWebSocketContainer.java:637) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.processResponse(WsWebSocketContainer.java:621) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:309) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:152) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:149) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0]
```

Upon further investigation I changed the server endpoint configuration based on  TomcatWebSocketTestServer.java used in StompWebSocketIntegrationTests.java as follows:

```
RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
registry.addEndpoint("/hello")
    .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy))
    .setAllowedOrigins("*");
```

I can now connect, but the browser clients cannot.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/hello/info 404 (Not Found)
```

If I add .withSockJs() to the endpoint configuration:

```
RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
registry.addEndpoint("/hello")
    .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy))
    .setAllowedOrigins("*")
    .withSockJs();
```

the browser clients can connect again, but the java client is back to the original error.

Should I be able to share the same endpoint between both clients or do I need to configure two separate endpoints in this case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following configuration works:

```
RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
registry.addEndpoint("/hello")
        .withSockJS();

registry.addEndpoint("/hello")
        .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy))
        .setAllowedOrigins("*");
```

Not sure if this is by design (i.e. two endpoints with the same path)?

A better solution based on Brian-Clozel's feedback is to use the java SockJsClient as a transport when configuring the WebSocketStompClient:

```
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(1);
transports.add(new WebSocketTransport( new StandardWebSocketClient()) );
WebSocketClient transport = new SockJsClient(transports);
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
```

which allows the use of only one endpoint to which the java and javascript clients can both connect:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
}
```

Comment: I think you can have it written as one though, no?

`registry.addEndpoint("/hello").setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy)).setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();`

Also, changed `setAllowedOrigins` to `setAllowedOriginPatterns`.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in [the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-fallback-sockjs-overview): when enabling SockJS, multiple transports are configured for you. First, the client sends a `"GET /info"` request to know about supported transports and then sends a request depending on its capabilities:

```
"http://host:port/myApp/myEndpoint/{server-id}/{session-id}/{transport}"
```

Now you don't need to duplicate your configuration for you `"/hello"` endpoint. You'd rather directly use the websocket endpoint, or better, use the Java SockJS client with a websocket transport. See [the complete example in the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-fallback-sockjs-client).

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful.  I have updated my answer with the new configuration based on your feedback.  Sorry I can't upvote yet (not enough reputation points).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the http filter(such as shiro filter) or HandlerInterceptor.

WebSocket connnect base on http connect, there is a ws url like this: ws://localhost:8080/ws-endpoint, If you have a http filter or http interceptor on the uri ws-endpoint, the http filter or http interceptor will be effect before websocket upgrade. So remove the uri's http filter or http interceptor.

Comment: Please explain this more

Comment: WebSocket connnect base on http connect, there is a ws url like this: ws://localhost:8080/ws-endpoint, If you have a http filter or http interceptor on the uri ws-endpoint, the http filter or http interceptor will be effect before websocket upgrade. So remove the uri's http filter or http interceptor. @jan-Černý