# spring websocket with digest authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket, digest-authentication

I use **Spring security** to authenticate my `spring websocket` server. It works fine with the `Basic authentication`, but it went wrong when I changed to `Digest authentication`. I don't know what to put into the headers. Does someone know any solutions?

This is the websocket client code snippet:

```
SockJsClient sockJsClient;
WebSocketStompClient stompClient;
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
......
```

***Update:***

It works well with digest for rest, the following codes can configure `RestTempalte` to use digest:

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.AuthCache;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;

public class HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryDigestAuth extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {

    public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryDigestAuth(HttpClient client) {
        super(client);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
        return createHttpContext(uri);
    }

    private HttpContext createHttpContext(URI uri) {
        // Create AuthCache instance
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        // Generate DIGEST scheme object, initialize it and add it to the local auth cache
        DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
        // If we already know the realm name
        digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "myrealm");
        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
        authCache.put(targetHost, digestAuth);

        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);
        return localcontext;
    }
}
```

Get a rest template:

```
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class RestTempleteConfig {

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider())
                .useSystemProperties().build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryDigestAuth(
                client);

        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }

    private CredentialsProvider provider() {
        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin");
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Use rest template:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTempleteConfig().getRestTemplate();
String uri = "http://localhost:8080/login";
ResponseEntity<String> entity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
System.out.println(entity.getBody());
```

Comment: What do you know about Digest algorithm? It is not just setting a header.

Comment: When a client sends a request to server, it will receive a 401 error for the first time. Then the client can get realm and nonce from the response header to send a subsequent request. I think it may be ok if I send the correct header but it's hard to get the nonce. But what's the right way to authenticate websocket with digest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. Configure `digest authentication` with `spring security` at the sever side, then change client implementation to this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTempleteConfig().getRestTemplate();

SockJsClient sockJsClient;
WebSocketStompClient stompClient;
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();

StandardWebSocketClient websocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
// add restTemplate first
transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport(restTemplate));
transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(websocketClient));
sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
```

The digest is configured in the `rest template`, what we need to do is to add it to `Transport list`. And you should add `rest template` first, then `websocket`, for it matters when creating the `sockJs` url. More details refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413380/websocketstompclient-wont-connect-to-sockjs-endpoint).